# XGBoost with objective as binary:logistic returning only binary value

Tags: xgboost, xgboost-classifier

I am training an xgboost model for binary classification using objective as 'binary:logistic'. The model should predict probability but it is outputting either 0 or 1. I want the model to output the probability. These are the parameters I am using
[image]
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: How are you getting the predictions from your model? It is likely that the default `predict` method automatically converts the probability to a 0/1 prediction, and that there's a separate method to get the underlying probability (e.g. see the `predict` and `predict_proba` methods for the [`LogisticRegression` in `scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

Comment: Thanks @Oxbowerce . Using predict_proba instead of predict worked.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer so you can accept it as an answer to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you getting the predictions from your model? It is likely that the default `predict` method automatically converts the probability to a 0/1 prediction, and that there's a separate method to get the underlying probability (e.g. see the `predict` and `predict_proba` methods for the [`LogisticRegression` in `scikit-learn`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)).